# Why Html.TextBoxFor is not cover the all page in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, html.textboxfor

I am using bootstrap form-control and I am trying to set my TextBoxFor element width as 100%. But it is shown like the picture below.

[page shown like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHedW.png)

My code is below.

```
@model LearnWord.Models.WordModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

<h2>Add New Word</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Word"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Word)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Word, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Meaning)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Meaning, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Synonyms)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Synonyms, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Sentences)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Sentences, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

And this is the _Layout.cshtml part which renders body.

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Created By ChivalrouS</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

I tried to set width as 100% but it is already like that. When I tried to change width with 100px or 200px it was work but TextBox did not cover the page as a 100%.

I checked the other topics but I can not find the solution for my problem.

Comment: It depends on the outer container. It takes 100% of the width of Outer container. So if you have like `col-lg-6` it will cover up the width of `col-lg-6` and so on

Comment: There is no constraint like that, in fact the <div> which contains that control is cover the page. When I added a border to <div> or outer part it is shown bigger than control. But control is not.

Comment: Can you paste your entire html of this page how it looks like?

Comment: what is the css for 'body-content'

Comment: It just set 'padding-right' and 'padding-left'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I fixed this issue.

In the css file there is a part which constraint the max-width as 280px for input, select and textarea. After I remove this part the problem was fixed.